# Connecting two OpenVZ internal networks so containers can see each other

Tags: networking, nat, bridge, openvz

I have two OpenVZ Hosts with containers on them. This is the current layout:

Host-A: (eth0 (connected to internet), eth1 (connected to Host-B))

Host-B: (eth0 (connected to internet), eth1 (connected to Host-A))

Host-A and Host-B have OpenVZ containers on them. Host-A and Host-B have one public IPv4 address (each), the containers do not have public IPs, they need to be on an internal private network.

How do I configure the network so containers on both hosts can communicate to one another and access the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting an overwhelming number of responses on SF... not!?!, I did my own research the figured it out. This is how I did it.

**Configuration**

-SSH to Host A and update /etc/network/interfaces as below:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.0.2.99
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address public_ip_here
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway public_ip_gateway_here

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.1.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.1.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

-SSH to Host B and updated /etc/network/interfaces as below:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.0.2.199
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address public_ip_here
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway public_ip_gateway_here

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.1.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.1.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

-On all new containers, create eth0 (->vmbr0) and eth1 (->vmbr1) and assign each eth interface a static IP from the appropriate block.

-On all new containers, ensure default route is pointing to 10.0.1.1, if not, then update network config files in container accordingly.

**Server Network Topology:**

- Host A (eth0: public IP, vmbr0: 10.0.1.0/24) (eth1/vmbr1:
  10.0.2.99/24)
- Host B (eth0: public IP, vmbr0: 10.0.1.0/24) (eth1/vmbr1:
  10.0.2.199/24)
- Containers (eth0-mapped-to->vmbr0: 10.0.1.[CT#]/24)
  (eth1-mapped-to->vmbr1: 10.0.2.[CT# if on host-a, else CT#+100]/24)
- Containers on both hosts can have the same IP in the 10.0.1.x IP
  block, but not in the 10.0.2.x IP block

**Sample Container Configuration:**

- Container # 100 on Host A (eth0->vmbr0: 10.0.1.100/24, gateway: 10.0.1.1) (eth1->vmbr1: 10.0.2.100/24, gateway: 10.0.2.99)
- Container # 100 on Host B (eth0->vmbr0: 10.0.1.100/24, gateway: 10.0.1.1) (eth1->vmbr1: 10.0.2.200/24, gateway: 10.0.2.199)
- Container # 101 on Host A (eth0->vmbr0: 10.0.1.101/24, gateway: 10.0.1.1) (eth1->vmbr1: 10.0.2.101/24, gateway: 10.0.2.99)
- Container # 101 on Host B (eth0->vmbr0: 10.0.1.101/24, gateway: 10.0.1.1) (eth1->vmbr1: 10.0.2.201/24, gateway: 10.0.2.199)

Comment: Self answering is also encouraged :)